# Convert Razor String Variable to Javascript String Variable in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to pass my string variable (even boolean) on my cshtml view to my javascript section. I can successfully pass the value from razor section to javascript if its integer. But what I want to accomplish is to pass the string value. Here is my sample code from my .cshtml:

```
string strAnnouncement = "My announcement";
int intCounterValue = 1200;
```

To receive the value on Javascript, here is my code:

```
//Cannot get the value, always error on Developer Tool console
var SessAnnouncement = @strAnnouncement;

//Can get the value successfully
var SessInitTimer = @intCounterValue;
```

As you can see, I can get the value via javascript on SessInitTimer which is 1200. But on SessAnnouncement, I get a **Uncaught ReferenceError: My announcement is not defined.**

How can I get the strAnnouncement value on my razor section and pass it on script section?

Comment: You have to enclose your C# variable into single or double quote if you want to access it in javascript.
ex:  var SessAnnouncement = '@strAnnouncement';

Answer (score 23, accepted):

They are treated as variable and since you have not defined them you get the said error.

You need to wrap in quotes to be treated as string.

```
var SessAnnouncement = "@strAnnouncement";
```

---

A better approach would be to use `JSON.Encode()` method

```
var SessAnnouncement = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(strAnnouncement));
```

Comment: That works for single values. If there are newlines in the string, JavaScript throws a syntax error exception.

Comment: @Suncat2000, for multiple line use backtick i.e. `\`@strAnnouncement\``. However, I would recommend the second approch

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but that works only if all your browsers support template literals. Internet Explorer does not. I ended up using `@(new HtmlString(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.XmlProcessedText, true)))` to encode the string and escape quotes. It worked perfectly.